# Задать MouseListener в анонимном классе

Tags: java, swing

Проблема вот в чём: сперва просит изменить wordList[i] на static. Меняю - просит изменить i на static. Смысла менять уже нет 100%. Подскажите, как сделать, чтоб заработало?

```
                    JButton[] wordList = showWords(wordPanel,searchField.getText(), 1);
                            for(int i=0; i<WORD_BTN_ARR_LEN-1;i++){
                                wordPanel.add(wordList[i]);                                 
                                wordList[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                                         wordList[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

Comment: Вероятно, IDE просит изменить wordList[i] и i не на static, а на final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы, вопрос решился иначе. Решение от jMind не подходит, так как проблема заключалась в запросе установления поля final, как указал Rams666. В принципе, Rams666 прав, но решение чревато тем, что я смогу создать только 1 final кнопку - остальные кнопки из массива идут лесом. Решение было таково, что я добавлял все listener при создании кнопки в showWords(...);, т.е. там мог сделать ее final и изгаляться как захочу.

Comment: Можно было вообще либо реализовать слушателя в данном классе, либо в другом.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
wordList[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
```

попробуйте

```
((JButton) e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.blue);
```

Answer (score 1):

В анонимный класс могут быть переданы только final переменные. Попробуйте переписать свой код следующим образом:

```
     for(int i=0; i<WORD_BTN_ARR_LEN-1;i++){
         wordPanel.add(wordList[i]);
         final JButton btn = wordList[i];
         wordList[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
              public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                  btn.setBackground(Color.blue);
             }
         });
     }
```